# slideshow display images not correctly

Tags: slideshow

I am creating my theme and I want to add a Slideshow to my theme but images not displaying in a correct form, they display below each other.
I also use Widgets for slideshow and I have used `Soliloquy Lite` and `Simple Slideshow Manager`.
How can I fix this?[image]

My site URL(just for this question): [Link](http://amirsasani.gigfa.com/)

Comment: Do you mind sharing a link to the page or the code you used to create the slideshow? That will help users to identify the problem and help you.

Comment: @Austin I added the link to question